# If the raw bits are copied, Is it still called casting?

Tags: c++, types, casting

When I cast a `float` to an `int`, for example:

```
float f = 32.4;
int i = (int)f;
```

The raw bits of `f` are not copied directly into `i`, but rather the bits that represent `32` are copied into `i`.

If the `int` casting worked differently and only copied the raw bits of `f` into `i`, does it still called casting? Or does casting means that the least amount of information that can be represented by the assigned type (`int` in this case) must be copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **cast** is the name of a syntax construct. These are all casts:

```
(any_typename) foo
static_cast<any_typename>(foo)
reinterpret_cast<any_typename>(foo)
```

A cast may also be called an *explicit conversion*. Conversions that are not written with cast notation are called *implicit*.

Conversions may or may not be implementable as a "raw bits copy". The conversion `int i = f;`  (with or without the cast operator - makes no difference) can't be. However, `long x = 5; int i = x;` could be, if `int` and `long` are the same size on that platform.

Another conversion that could be a raw bit copy is `char *ptr = "hello"; void *q = ptr;`.  In general, other pointer conversions might not be raw bit copies.

Conversions between user-defined types (i.e. class types) can only occur if the class has a conversion operator or converting constructor defined, and in this case you write code that specifies how the conversion is performed.

Answer (score 2):

What you've shown is still called casting.  If you want to copy the raw bits, you can use memcpy:

```
int i;
static_assert(sizeof(i) == sizeof(f), "oops");
memcpy(&i, &f, sizeof(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

A C cast can do any of `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` or `const_cast`, or even a combination of two such, depending on the context. And that's why it's very dangerous notation: its meaning can change very unexpectedly when the code is maintained. A C cast can even give you access to an inaccessible base, which no named cast can.

A `reinterpret_cast` is intended to keep the bits, although that's up to the implementation.

It can only cast pointers and references. However, that may not have been the <sup>1</sup>original intention, and it's easily circumvented by just writing e.g. `reinterpret_cast<U&>( t_instance )`. Anyway, when you do a `reinterpret_cast` you're usually in formally Undefined Behavior land, *but* relying on platform- and/or compiler guarantees: you are taking the responsibility for the portability of your code, if any, and not leaving that to the standard's guarantees.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>) Judging by an attempted but invalid `reinterpret_cast` in some code that I once had private access to, i.e., this is an informed opinion.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

According to the explanation found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion), 'casting' means that a type conversion takes place. Depending on the type and the definition of the cast, this might be just copying of the raw data as well as a sophisticated interpretation mechanism. There is no requirement for the cast to work in either way; however a copy of the raw data usually is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: why use Wikipedia when there's a perfectly good C++ standard?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Good point. This document http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf Subsection 6.5.4 ("Semantics") mentions that a cast operator 'converts the value'. Does this mean that a mere copy of the bits is ruled out?

Comment: The identity conversion is still a conversion :)

Comment: That's the C standard BTW; for links to C++ drafts [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents)

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, is my answer still correct in the sense that, especially as the cast operator can be overloaded in C++, neither interpretation of the value nor a bitwise copy is completely ruled out?

Comment: by "interpretation" I think you mean a conversion other than a bitwise copy.  (The word "reinterpret" means something else in C++)

Comment: Yes exactly; by "interpretation" I mean "calculation of a value that is not a bitwise copy and tries to represent the value to be converted in a meaningful way" (as in a cast from `float` to `int`).